# Злоупотребление алкоголем или алкоголя?

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: "Злоупотребление алкоголем" или "злоупотребление алкоголя"?
Хотелось бы узнать обоснованное мнение, т.е. почему именно так, а не иначе.

Answer (score 2):

> А мы тут, знаете, всё **плюшками** балуемся. (балуемся *кем? чем?* - творительный падеж - "плюшк**ами**")
>   Злоупотребление **плюшками** может быть опасно! (опять творительный падеж)

Аналогично с алкоголем:

> A мы тут, знаете, всё **алкоголем** злоупотребляем. (злоупотребляем *кем? чем?* - творительный падеж - "алког**олем**")
>   Злоупотребление **алкоголем** может быть опасно! (опять творительный падеж)

Но заметьте, что существуют слова **употреблять** и **употребление** - без приставки **зло** - и они требуют постановки зависимого слова в винительный и родительный падежи:

> A мы тут, знаете, всё **алкоголь** употребляем. (употребляем *кого? что?* - винительный падеж - "алког**оль**")
>   Употребление **алкоголя** может быть опасно! (употребление *кого? чего?* - родительный падеж - "алкого**ля**")

Так как слова "употребление" и "злоупотребление" звучат похоже, и еще оттого, что "употребление алког**оля**" - распространенное словосочетание (и, увы, явление), то нас порой тянет сказать "злоупотребление алкоголя", смешав две разные формы.

Вот и выходит неправильное употребление **падежей**, или злоупотребление **падежами** (но не "злоупотребление *падежей*"!)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.

Я думаю, что когда человек проговаривает "злоупотребление алкого..", то мозг по привычке группирует "употребление алкого.." и автоматически добавляет "ем", т.к. первый корень "зл" как бы скрадывается из-за большой дистанции: "употребление" - довольно большое слово. Мозгу не важна формальная грамматика, важно уметь быстро засекать знакомые паттерны, вроде "употребление алкоголя". Интересно, какие еще бывают сочетания слов, в которых из-за этого эффекта по ошибке ставят не те окончания.

P.P.S.

Чтобы "сломать" этот паттерн, можно попробовать переставить местами слова:

> Алкоголя употребление изменяет поведение.
>   Алкоголя злоупотребление изменяет поведение. (чувствуется диссонанс: словно бы это алкоголь сам "злоупотребляет")

Answer (score 1):

Злоупотребить можно чем-то, а не что. Правильно: алкоголем.

Глагол злоупотребить требует после себя творительного падежа.

См.Малый академический словарь. — М.: Институт русского языка Академии наук СССР. Евгеньева А. П.. 1957—1984.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан справедливо, потому что в САР 1789-94 соответствующая статья гласит :

> Злоупотребляю, ешь... Употребляю во зло, во вредъ что. **Злоупотреблять деньги. Злоупотреблять благосклонность, довѣренность начальника.**

Данный текст повторен в Словаре 1847 года. Словарь Даля также фиксирует винительный падеж : злоупотреблять что.
Очевидно, что творительный падеж при глаголе злоупотреблять появился по аналогии с формой : *злоупотребление чем-то*.

Comment: Да, вы правы, даже в 18 веке встречается В.п. , например: "Показывайте им, сколь мало истинной цены имеют наружные сии преимущества...и коль презренным делают они его, когда он либо ЗЛОУПОТРЕБЛЯЕТ ИХ, либо менее добродетелен и полезен бывает, нежели другой..." [Н. И. Новиков. О воспитании и наставлении детей (1783)].

Comment: Но мне кажется, что переход к Т.п. связан с использованием глагола с отвлеченными существительными,  а также со сложной семантикой слова (употреблять что-то во зло), в этом случае  прямое дополнения  лучше заменить косвенным и использовать Т.п., так как  у Т.п. основным является значение орудийной семантики (всё, что способствует осуществлению действия и придает ему известный вид, форму, образ.

Comment: При разных падежах мы получаем разный смысл : *злоупотребил ее любовь* (= насытился и бросил),  но *злоупотребил ее любовью* (= воспользовался доверием человека и совершил преступление).

Comment: >Н. И. Новиков. О воспитании и наставлении детей (1783) 

>Чрез то наложили бы вы на них несносное бремя и
некоторым образом принудили бы их к неповиновению;
либо сделали бы вы их робкими невольниками, с
величайшею нетерпеливостию дожидающимися той
минуты, в которую могут они без наказания **злоупотребить
свою свободу.**